# What's an easy way to manage local/development/production configuration files in PHP projects?

Tags: php, configuration, app-config, configuration-files, conflict

I would like to have seperate copies of configuration files for local/dev/production, but not have them interfere with each other and possibly be able to co-exist in version control.

What is an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: I find the [Zend configuration component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) pretty intuitive and easy for this purpose; and use an environment variable to indicate which server (production/staging/test/dev/etc)

Comment: This Zend Framework 1 thing has been criticized for allowing failure too easy. The configuration for both development and production is known to the application, and the only reason why the development server does not affect the production database is because of an environment variable that can be forgotten! How do you fail? Having the new development machine use production data, or the new production server run on development data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 

// rename this file to whatever your configuration file is supposed to be called (wp-config.php, etc.).

switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']):

// assuming your local server name is 'localhost,' leave this section alone
    case 'localhost':
        require_once('local.config.php');
        break;

// replace production-url with the server name for your production site
    case 'production-url':
        require_once('production.config.php');
        break;

// replace development-url with the server name for your development site
    case 'development-url':
        require_once('development.config.php');
        break;

    default:
     // something went wrong;

endswitch;
// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

[Source](https://github.com/micahbolen/Smart-PHP-Config-File)